# Listening for an event of only enter/return key (not others)

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I want to bind an event for the Enter key. I can use the standard way of binding the keydown event to the textbox and then using the keycode of Enter key(13), I can add my code. 
 For example: [standard way to bind event on keydown](http://www.liveweave.com/V1KdFb)

But the problem here is that, the function will be called for every key that I press, even though I want to use it only for the Enter key. 
Is there a way by which I can optimize this event handler function to respond to only the Enter key?

Comment: The event being called and ignored for every key that is not Enter is not a big issue as you think. If there was an optimized way that handled it - it would of done the same.. it would listen to all keys and check if it's the enter key. Just use the keydown event :)

Comment: Thanks Adam. My only concern was about the performance. But if there is no other method then I guess I'll continue with this only.

Answer (score 4):

Check the `which` property from the `event` object:

```
//'13' is the enter key
if (event.which == 13) {
    //do stuff
} else {
    return false;
}
```